# How to send a fax with restcomm?

Tags: restcomm

is it possible to send a document (pdf) through fax in restcomm?
While searching in the mailing list i found that in the past it was only possible throught interfax.Is there a way to send it directly ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure i get your question.

There is RCML verb to send faxes https://www.restcomm.com/docs/connect/rcml/fax-rcml.html#fax . Embedding a PDF document in the RCML verb should be supported.

If you are wondering how the actual fax provider is configured, I guess this is limited to current hardcoded impl https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/blob/master/restcomm/restcomm.fax/src/main/java/org/restcomm/connect/fax/InterfaxService.java which is based by the aforementioned InterFax provider.

If you are looking for a configurable API, we could potentially guide you to contribute a PR for this. We follow similar approach for other services...